# Updating cells on an open Excel sheet while switching application.screenupdating off and on

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

This is a small issue with a large macro I am making reading through log files and preparing data by writing them into a number of worksheets. I don't want to see all of this writing going on, so I turn screen updating off, however I want to see some progress so every now and then I switch screen updating on I activate the top worksheet, write some progress data in some cells and switch screen updating off again. This worked pretty well in Excel 2010, but last week I upgraded to Excel 2013 and no more updating visible until the macro finishes. I added a 0.3 second pause, but now only the time gets updated and not the number of processed sites. Any ideas?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True  'To write the elapsed time and the number of found sites on the performance monitor sheet
PerfMon.Activate
PerfMon.Range("B4") = Now - StartPoint
PerfMon.Range("D4") = SiteCnt
Application.Wait (Now + (0.3 / 86400))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Thanks, Hans

Comment: I don't have 2013, but perhaps try instead using the `StatusBar` to keep track of progress instead.  See [Chip Pearson's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/statusbar.htm) page, or [this page](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/statusbar.html) for some ideas. (I'm not sure if the `StatusBar` is affected by `ScreenUpdating` though, but I don't think it is).

Comment: That was an unexpected end. Anyway, what I wanted to say is: a big thanks to both of you. Both solutions work. I imagine that the StatusBar would be the MS preferred solution, whereas the DoEvents is mine.

Comment: `DoEvents` yields execution so that the operating system can process other events. There is a caution in its description but it is the standard way of pausing the main process so background stuff can be actioned.

Comment: To show progress I prefer to use a modeless userform. A modeless userform requires no action from the user but the macro can write to it. You could have a progress bar but I usually prefer informative displays.  If I am processing 1,000 rows, I will have fixed labels containing "Row", "of" and "1,000" and one to which I write the current row number so the form reads "Record N of 1,000" with N running from 1 to 1,000. With multi-stage macros, I list all the stages and report progress through them.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution seems to be enabling the status bar. Without knowing exactly what your macro is, I would suggest you set one of the variables in your workbook as an integer and keep track of the current progress in the status bar. Maybe this is "Now - StartPoint" or "SiteCnt," otherwise you can periodically have the status bar update with new text.

If you go with the integer option, here is an example:

```
[...]
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
 Dim i As Integer
 For i = 2 To Sheets.Count       ' example from my macro but you could use any repeating process
       Worksheets(i).Activate
       Application.StatusBar = "Updating Filings for " & ( i - 1 ) & " of " & (Sheets.Count - 1) & "   |   " & Format (( i - 1 )) / (Sheets.Count - 1), "0%") & "Complete"
 Next i
 Application.StatusBar = ""
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
[...]
```

If you go with the text option, here is an example:

```
[...]
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
 Application.StatusBar = "Reading log files"
 [...]
 Application.StatusBar = "Preparing data"
 [...]
 Application.StatusBar = "Formatting data"
 [...]
 Application.StatusBar = ""
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
[...]
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your effort. Indeed the statusbar option is probably the best. There is one comment I have about the DoEvents though. My macro runs for a bit more than an hour. I was able to open another instance of Excel during the operation of the macro to work on other stuff. I looks like  DoEvents blocks that option until the macro ends.

I consider this issue solved.

Thanks everybody!

Hans